# How can I get 1 array contains many object to create a JSON file from my code?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I have this website that I want to scrape data from it.

From page 1, there're contains 30 items, page 2, 30 items, and so on until the last page.

What I want (it'll contain all data from many pages):

```
[
  // All push go into 1 array
  {
  animeURL: "animeURL",
  animeTitle: "animeTitle"
  },
  {
  animeURL: "animeURL",
  animeTitle: "animeTitle"
  },
  ...
]
```

From my code, I've succeeded to get what I want, but the problem is it's being separated by many arrays due to different push I guess.

What I get in console.log:

```
// Array from the first push match with first loop
    [
      {
      animeURL: "animeURL",
      animeTitle: "animeTitle"
      },
      {
      animeURL: "animeURL",
      animeTitle: "animeTitle"
      },
    ]
// Array from the first push + second push match with second loop.
    [
      {
      animeURL: "animeURL",
      animeTitle: "animeTitle"
      },
      {
      animeURL: "animeURL",
      animeTitle: "animeTitle"
      },
    ]
// ... array from page 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

Here's my code:

```
const PORT = 8000
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()



function fetchAnimeData() {
    let animeData = []
    for (i = 1; i<3; i++){
        let url = `https://animehay.club/loc-phim/W1tdLFtdLFtdLFtdXQ==/trang-${i}.html`;
        axios(url)
        .then(response =>{
            const html = response.data
            const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: true})
    
            $('.movie-item', html).each(function(){
                const animeUrl = $(this).find('a').attr('href')
                const animeTitle = $(this).find('a').attr('title')
                animeData.push({
                  animeUrl, animeTitle
                })
            })
            console.log(animeData)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
 
}

fetchAnimeData()

app.listen(PORT, ()=> {console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${PORT}`)})
```

I've tried to move the `animeData` variable around or let it be a global variable and console.log around, some only get [], some will remain the same like the problem I occurred, how can I console.log and print out the result that I want, which is only 1 array contains many pages data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep track of your promises:

```
let jobs = []
```

and in every loop

```
jobs.push(axios(url) ...etc )
```

In the end you wait for all jobs to be settled:

```
Promise.all(jobs).then(()=>{
    console.log(animeData);
})
```

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, I've been stuck for like... half of my day.